# Documentation: Proposed Changes shows proposed changes for review, but no pending review items inside

Tags: support, documentation

On main review page it shows 1 Proposed Changes for Documentation but, while go inside documentation review page it shows:

> There are currently no pending review items matching your filters;
>   please change your filters or check back later.

[image]

[image]

Comment: IIRC, those values are cached, and cached well. By the time you get into the queue, it's likely the reviews have already been cleared. Documentation reviews seem to go by rather quickly.

Comment: Additionally, pending changes don't get approved quickly. I have added substantial changes to some examples 6 days ago and still I can see only the rudamentary old version (of my own examples!). This is way faster in the normal question and answer mode of Stack Overflow. Please make the process less bureocratic or the Documentation will not be a benefit for the users.